# how to add a variable inside a string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending some html into a list, but having trouble passing the selected_files.name value into the function.  Please see the onclick below

```
for (var i = 0; i < selected_files.length; ++i) {
    children += '<div class="del" onclick="javascript:removeImageFromList(selected_files[i].name)">X</div>' + selected_files[i].name + '<br>';
}
```

What is the proper way to pass this in?  When I log from inside the removeImageFromList function it is receiving a `selected_files[i].name` as a string rather than the value.

Comment: There's lots to improve here, but for this you need to start and stop the string around the variable, just like you've done between the div and br tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It would be easy to read and You can get rid to remember where to add `+` and `""`.

Just for example I've simulated `selected_files` as an array with `name` property.

```js
const selected_files = [{ name: "first"}, {name: "second"}];
let children = "";

for (var i = 0; i < selected_files.length; ++i) {
  children += `<div class="del" onclick="javascript:removeImageFromList(${selected_files[i].name})">X</div>${selected_files[i].name}<br>`;
}

console.log( children );
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the value contained in the object, you need to do what you did later in the string:

```
children += '<div class="del" onclick="javascript:removeImageFromList(' + selected_files[i].name + ')">X</div>' + selected_files[i].name + '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code snippet

```js
var selected_files=[{name:'abc'}, {name:'xyz'}]

var children='';
for (var i = 0; i < selected_files.length; ++i) {
    children += '<div class="del" onclick="javascript:removeImageFromList(\''+selected_files[i].name+'\')">X</div>' + selected_files[i].name + '<br>';
}

console.log('children--->',children);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your function-call-variable outside the string like you already did at the end.

Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < selected_files.length; ++i) {
    children += '<div class="del" onclick="javascript:+removeImageFromList('+selected_files[i].name)+'">X</div>' + selected_files[i].name + '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems:

- you are appending html (a div) as a string, which is prone to spelling errors. your editor won't correct strings but it will correct javascript.
- you are actually adding javascript inside that string. I would say that is a definite no-no in code land....

You can solve this problem by creating DOM elements the javascript way. Then you can add an eventListener to respond to mouse clicks.

```
let selected_files = [{name:"henk"},{name:"wim"}]

for (let i = 0; i < selected_files.length; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement("div")
  div.classList.add("del")
  div.innerText = selected_files[i].name
  div.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      removeImageFromList(selected_files[i].name)
  })
  document.body.appendChild(div)
}

function removeImageFromList(str){
  console.log(str)
}
```